# Swift Firestore check if the document exist.. not working in my case even the document exist in the collection

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firebase Auth with google signing to login user to my IOS app.I have a step which checks if the user exists in the /users collection.. The document id is nothing but UID.  If the user login for the first time, it will create a document in the /users collection else it will load the user information into the variables.. However, with my code below, it does not say user exists even though the document(UID) exist in the collection for the repeated users..

```
db.collection("users").document(Auth.auth().currentUser.uid).getDocument { (snapshot, error ) in
    if  (snapshot?.exists)! {
         print("User Document exist")                    
    } else {                    
         print("User Document does not exist")                    
    }
}
```

I have tried different methods.. I also wanted to check for once.. Please advise

Comment: Your code looks fine. So if this prints "User Document exist", I'd be inclined to think that a document with an ID the same as the user's UID really does exist in the `users` collection.

Comment: The UID already exists.. If I login again with the  same user, it is not even coming into the IF..ELSE stmt..

Comment: Did you check if you get an error?

Comment: Check the value of `Auth.auth().currentUser.uid` right before you use it to load the document. It could be that the `currentUsers` isn't refreshed yet. For this type of code, it's best to put it in an auth state change listener as shown in the *first* sample here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user

Comment: No error.. Its simply not checking the documents